# Offline install order of Conda packages

Tags: installation, anaconda, conda, package-managers, offlineapps

We've recently installed Anaconda to a corporate environment. Unfortunately, due to various IT and network policies in place, we're unable to use the normal conda install methods that go to the continuum repository. We end up getting an http error due to some sort of port blocking.

```
conda install nodejs
Fetching package metadata ...

CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None
for url <None>

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
ProxyError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.continuum.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000002C597B8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)))",),)
```

What we have been able to do, however, is to manually download *.tar.bz2 files from https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/ and perform an offline install.

```
conda install ./nodejs-8.9.3-hd6b2f15_0.tar.bz2
```

Now, my questions is surrounding packages which are lists of other packages to be installed. The package we'd like to get installed is r-essentials. But looking into the recipe contained within https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64/r-essentials-3.4.3-r343_0.tar.bz2, there are 200+ packages that are listed, some which are already installed as part of Anaconda 5.1.0, and others specific to r-essentials we would need to download.

Let's say we go through the painstaking process of downloading all the packages. Some questions I had:

- Can we we create a batch file to run through the offline conda install for each indivual package? Or is there a better way to batch install over 100 offline packages?
- Is there any harm if a package in our batch installer is one that had previously already been installed? Or will it just skip over already installed packages?
- Is there a specific order the packages need to be installed?
- If in the future, IT unblocks our port access, can we update packages installed offline through the repository?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue installing packages and their dependencies on an offline server.

My solution has been to do a 'dry-run' install on an internet connected server and have conda work out the dependencies. The 'dry-run' output is piped to a json file, as per these examples.

```
${HOME}/anaconda3/bin/conda install --dry-run \
cx_oracle \
sqlparse \
ujson \
--json > /tmp/anaconda_channel_pkgs.json

${HOME}/anaconda3/bin/conda install --dry-run --channel conda-forge \
altair \
python-xxhash \
--json > /tmp/condaforge_channel_pkgs.json
```

I then process the json files, download the required packages, and create a tar'd package bundle and instructions suitable for installing on an offline server, using this [script](https://gist.github.com/davecoutts/6ed4db0f23adc0f824fd9a64067b6594).

Its has worked for me on Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64. I hope it helps.